# What method would I use to refer to objects in an array?

Tags: vb.net

I am not sure if this is possible or where to begin, so hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

I would like to have a function that does a For Each on objects in an array

For example if car is an object and car.speed car.passengers and car.wheels are all object properties, I would like to do something like:

```
for each (object declared as a car)

myvariable1 = (objectname).wheels

myvariable2 = (objectname).speed
```

etc

What is the name of what I'm trying to do so I can research it more? I assume I would save the object names to some kind of array, but not sure how that would work.

thanks!

Comment: `For Each c As Car In CarsArray`  but that assumes the array is declared to contain `Car` objects, not generic `System.Object`.  but then it would be `c.Wheels` without the parens etc.  [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)

Comment: Got it, thanks. I will check that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
    Dim myvariable1 As Integer 'Number of wheels on car
    Dim myvariable2 As Double
    For Each c As Car In CarArray
        myvariable1 = c.wheels
        myvariable2 = c.speed
    Next
```